# For ordinals, if $\beta \leq \alpha < \beta + \gamma$ then $\alpha = \beta + \delta$ for some $\delta < \gamma$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I need to show, for ordinals $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$, that:

if $\beta \leq \alpha < \beta + \gamma$ then $\alpha = \beta + \delta$ for some $\delta < \gamma$.

I understand this should follow by well-orderedness of ordinals, but I'm not sure of how to phrase it precisely. (I actually need to show it for specific ordinals, but I feel it is true in this general form)

Comment: What can you use to solve this exercise? In particular, are you allowed to use subtraction between ordinals?

Comment: @MarcoVergamini Just definitions and associativity of ordinal addition, which is indeed subtly used in the second step of Hagen's proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By well-orderedness, there exists a minimal $\delta$ with $\alpha\le \beta+\delta$.

- If $\delta=0$, we see that $\beta\le \alpha\le \beta$, hence $\alpha=\beta+0$, as desired.
- If $\delta=\epsilon+1$, the from $\beta+\epsilon<\alpha\le(\beta+\epsilon)+1$, we conclude $\alpha=\beta+\epsilon+1$, as desired.
- If $\delta$ is a limit ordinal, then $\beta+\delta$ is the limit of all $\beta+\epsilon$, $\epsilon<\delta$. As $\alpha >\beta+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon<\delta$, we have $\alpha\ge \beta+\delta$ and once again $\alpha=\beta+\delta$.

Of course, once we have $\alpha=\beta+\delta$, it is clear from $\alpha<\beta+\gamma$ that $\delta<\gamma$.

Comment: Your previous to last $\delta$ should be $\gamma$. It may be worth pointing out that for any $\alpha$, $\alpha<\beta+(\alpha+1)$, and so you get that in fact any ordinal $\alpha\ge\beta$ has the form $\beta+\delta$ for some $\delta$.

Comment: Thank you both, Hagen's proof is neat! The last implication to reach the conclusion may deserve its own induction, but that's very straightforward.